# How to find the pixels of a texture for a certain face

Tags: python, uv, image

I'm making a script that determines the color of a face, based on the texture. I have an object that is UV unwrapped and has a texture assigned. What I would like to do is find the pixels that are in the UV space of a certain face.

[image: How to find the pixels covering the UV space of the selected face?]

I have something that works, but it is terribly slow. For every face I loop over all pixels of the texture image and determine if they are inside the UV space of the face. Not the best method I think :D

In the Python API documentation I found something about [MeshTextureFace](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_3/bpy.types.MeshTextureFace.html?highlight=face%20textures) and this seems exactly what I need. But I have no idea how I could use this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the sounds of it, you just need to optimize what you have.

Some suggestions.

- Don't check *every pixel*, at the very least calculate a bounding box around the face's UV's and only check those pixels.
- Rather then do a point-in-polygon test for each pixel. Use a scan-line method. See:  [Darel Rex Finley's Efficient Polygon Fill](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon_fill), Or Blenders version of it [fill_poly_v2i_n](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/blenlib/intern/math_geom.c;3b4a8f1cfa7339f3db9ddd4a7974b8cc30d7ff0b$2411)

Note that being a scripting language Python isn't ideal for these tasks - but it can likely be sped up enough to be usable as long as you don't need real-time feedback.

---

Update, made a more efficient version of Darel Rex's algorithm, [see link](https://gist.github.com/ideasman42/983738130f754ef58ffa66bcdbbab892).
(avoids looping over **all coordinates** for each y-pixel).

Comment: Thanks Campbell, I will try to use the method of Darel Rex Finely. So there is no 'easy' way? No access to some already existing functionality in Blender I could use?

Comment: @jasperge, no, generally per-pixel operations are not very good to do in Python, so we dont provide helper functions for these kinds of tasks. It shouldn't be too hard to port `fill_poly_v2i_n` to Python (think it reads a little easier then the original).

Comment: Sorry, for slow reaction. I finally got around to implement the `fill_poly_v2i_n`. Together with some other optimizations (still no bounding box), the processing time went from a few hours to a few minutes!

Comment: @jasperge would be good if you could post the code here, or at least a link to it.

Comment: Indeed it would. But the problem is it's too much tied in with the rest of the code. I will see if I can get the core part out and post it here.